# Amazon Affiliate links on a website written by users

Tags: affiliate

If my users link to amazon in their messages, I want to get commission on purchases. How do I do this? Do I have to learn Amazon web services or just register my website with Amazon Affiliate program?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need an affiliate account. You will then need to write code that takes users' posts, detects links to Amazon.com in them, and adds your affiliate code to those links.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should register your website with Amazon Affiliate program then you will code to place on your websites. This will enable to amazon to find out that how many visitors are coming through your websites and who purchase products or anything. It will enable you to get commission for each purchasing refer by your website. Complete details is here:http://www.tictacdo.com/pages/template-display.jsp?id=ActivityTemplate15gt4p6cdmr